# Matrix ordinary differential equation M(z)X(z)-X'(z)=0

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following ordniary differential equation matrix system:

$M(z)\begin{pmatrix}A(z)\\a(z)\end{pmatrix}-\partial_z \begin{pmatrix}A(z)\\a(z)\end{pmatrix}=0$

where we are searching the functions $a(z)$ and $A(z)$ and the Matrix

$M(z)=\begin{pmatrix}c&B(z)\\B(z)&d\end{pmatrix}$

is known.

Very naively I was first writing down the solution

$\begin{pmatrix}A(z)\\a(z)\end{pmatrix}=\exp\left[F(z)\right]\begin{pmatrix}A_0\\a_0\end{pmatrix}$

where

$F(z)=\int_0^zdz'M(z')$

but then I noticed that $[F,M]\neq 0$ in my case. Therefore I think what I have done is wrong.

I think people have thought about this already, but I cannot find something. Can I write down a general solution to my ordinary differential equation somehow?

Many thanks!

Comment: So the $M_{11}(z)  = c$, and $c \ne 0$ necessarily, right?

Comment: Right! I have to mention that I forgot another diagonal entry of the Matrix $M$. It is now corrected in the original post. However I think I know now to write down a formal solution. Make the Ansatz $\begin{pmatrix}A(z)\\a(z)\end{pmatrix}=U(z)\begin{pmatrix}A_0\\a_0\end{pmatrix}$ and plug it into the differential equation. One then gets an equation for $U$ as: $MU-i\partial_zU=0$. One can solve this iteratively $U=1+i\int_{z_0}^zdz'M(z')U(z')=\cdots$. However I am not sre how to choose $z_0$? It could be any value? And I have also chosen the '$1+$' constant? I did it to get a Dyson series...